# I can't get ambient temperature using emulator with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, android-sensors

I can't get the ambient temperature with the android emulator , Is it necessary to have an android device to test the sensors ?
Although I added the temperature support in the emulator and followed the ambient temperature part of this tutorial , I still get a null temperature value, so any suggestions plz ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sensor Simulator](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) to simulate temperature input, as well as inputs from the other hardware sensors.

Comment: the problem with the sensor simulator is that it does not supprot The 'TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE' and it only uses 'TYPE_TEMPERATURE' and I get a null value

Comment: Im using the Sensor simulator and I having problems this is the new post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385345/how-to-work-with-android-and-sensorsimulator-to-get-sensors-values-and-store-the

Answer (score 0):

The Sensor Simulator still only recognizes the deprecated `TYPE_TEMPERATURE` and not `TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE` as of version25.2.2-3098464.  Try this:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
senseTemperature = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
if (senseTemperature == null) {
    senseTemperature = mSensorManager
            .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE);
}
```